# Accumulation Function and Discount Rate (Monthly) (Financial Mathematics)

Tags: calculus, integration, finance, actuarial-science

> A deposit of \$300 is made into a fund at time 0.  The fund pays interest for the first three years at a nominal monthly rate of discount $d^{(12)}$.  For $t=3$ to $t=7$, interest is credited according to the force of interest $\delta(t)=(3t+3)^{-1}$.  As of time $t=7$, the accumulated value of the fund is \$574.  Calculate $d^{(12)}$.

I assumed I needed to solve the equation:

$$300(1-\frac{d^{(12)}}{12})^{-12\cdot3}\cdot e^{\int_3^7 (3t+3)^{-1}dt}=574$$

for $d^{(12)}$.  However, this ends up giving me a negative result, which makes no sense in the context of this problem, so clearly I'm not doing something correctly.

What is the correct equation to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Your equation of value appears correct.  I get $d^{(12)} \approx 0.138461$.  In particular,

$$\int_3^7 \frac{dt}{3t+3} = \frac{\log 2}{3},$$ so that $$d^{(12)} = 12 \left( 1 - \left(\frac{574}{300 \cdot 2^{1/3}}\right)^{-1/36}\right).$$